# When trying to Install NPM get an "npm ERR!"

Tags: json, node.js, ubuntu

When I'm trying to install: `alphaunlimitedg@AUNs-PC:~/chatapplication$ npm install` within terminal in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

This is btw my chat application, I was working on:

```
    {
    "name":"chat",
    "version":"0.0.1",
    "private":"true",
    "dependencies":
    {
        "socket.io":"1.4.8",
        "express":"4.14.0",
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
alphaunlimitedg@AUNs-PC:~$ npm info socket.io version
1.4.8
alphaunlimitedg@AUNs-PC:~$ npm info express version
4.14.0
alphaunlimitedg@AUNs-PC:~$ cd chat application
bash: cd: chat: No such file or directory
alphaunlimitedg@AUNs-PC:~$ cd chat application
bash: cd: chat: No such file or directory
alphaunlimitedg@AUNs-PC:~$ cd /home/chat application
bash: cd: /home/chat: No such file or directory
alphaunlimitedg@AUNs-PC:~$ cd /home/chat application/
bash: cd: /home/chat: No such file or directory
alphaunlimitedg@AUNs-PC:~$ pwd
/home/alphaunlimitedg
alphaunlimitedg@AUNs-PC:~$ cd /home/alphaunlimitedg/chat application
bash: cd: /home/alphaunlimitedg/chat: No such file or directory
alphaunlimitedg@AUNs-PC:~$ cd /home/alphaunlimitedg/chat application/
bash: cd: /home/alphaunlimitedg/chat: No such file or directory
alphaunlimitedg@AUNs-PC:~$ cd chatapplication
alphaunlimitedg@AUNs-PC:~/chatapplication$ npm install
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-28-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.5
npm ERR! file /home/alphaunlimitedg/chatapplication/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token '.' at 3:15
npm ERR!    "version":""0.0.1",
npm ERR!                 ^
npm ERR! File: /home/alphaunlimitedg/chatapplication/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/alphaunlimitedg/chatapplication/npm-debug.log
alphaunlimitedg@AUNs-PC:~/chatapplication$ npm install
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-28-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.5
npm ERR! file /home/alphaunlimitedg/chatapplication/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Trailing comma in object at 8:2
npm ERR!    }
npm ERR!    ^
npm ERR! File: /home/alphaunlimitedg/chatapplication/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/alphaunlimitedg/chatapplication/npm-debug.log
alphaunlimitedg@AUNs-PC:~/chatapplication$ npm install
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-28-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.5
npm ERR! file /home/alphaunlimitedg/chatapplication/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! No value found for key dependencies at 5:17
npm ERR!    "dependencies":,
npm ERR!                   ^
npm ERR! File: /home/alphaunlimitedg/chatapplication/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/alphaunlimitedg/chatapplication/npm-debug.log
alphaunlimitedg@AUNs-PC:~/chatapplication$ npm install
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-28-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.5
npm ERR! file /home/alphaunlimitedg/chatapplication/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Trailing comma in object at 9:2
npm ERR!    }
npm ERR!    ^
npm ERR! File: /home/alphaunlimitedg/chatapplication/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/alphaunlimitedg/chatapplication/npm-debug.log
alphaunlimitedg@AUNs-PC:~/chatapplication$ npm install
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-28-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.5
npm ERR! file /home/alphaunlimitedg/chatapplication/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Trailing comma in object at 10:1
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! ^
npm ERR! File: /home/alphaunlimitedg/chatapplication/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/alphaunlimitedg/chatapplication/npm-debug.log
```

I've tried several attempts above as you can see to execute the npm install command line.

But for some reason this didn't work, where I'm guessing it's a version error/problem within how my OS in Ubuntu is not supported or .json must be  an actual JSON file as in the code isn't completed yet? and not just JavaScript as the error describes itself.

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: You have an extra comma after express, try to remove it

Comment: Check your `package.json`. Your `package.json` is not in valid JSON format and contains error near  8:2. May be a trailing comma :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your file is invalid, remove the last comma in dependencies:

```
{
    "name":"chat",
    "version":"0.0.1",
    "private":"true",
    "dependencies":
    {
        "socket.io":"1.4.8",
        "express":"4.14.0"
    }
}
```

Next time use a JSON validator, like [this](http://jsonlint.com/), and you'll see what's wrong in your file:

```
Error: Parse error on line 7:
...ss": "4.14.0",       }    }
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', got '}'
```

Also, looking to your output, if you create a directory with a space, then you need to escape it to access it, so this:

```
cd chat application/
```

should be

```
cd chat\ application/
```

Comment: @AlphaUnlimitedG if this answer has solved your issue, please accept it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer